# .htaccess configuration issue with CodeIgniter on GoDaddy

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, codeigniter, ion-auth

I'm having issues with CodeIgniter (version 3.4) on GoDaddy where my `sub-controllers` are not being found after my `default controller` has been correctly instantiated through a login portal using `ion_auth`. Currently, all my website files are located within a `sub-folder` on my GoDaddy File Manager

Below are the configurations that I'm currently using...

**.htaccess**

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
```

**config.php**

```
$path = "http://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . str_replace(basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']),"",$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
$config['base_url'] = $path;
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';
```

> Before hosting on GoDaddy, I was using WAMP Server to host the website
>   and had no issues whatsoever with this configuration.

What can I do to get CodeIgniter configured properly with GoDaddy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add `RewriteBase` for your sub-folder like

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /subfolder/
....
....
RewriteRule . /subfolder/index.php [L]
```

Comment: Results in the following errors unfortunately.
`The requested URL /subfolder/index.php was not found on this server.`

`Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.`

Comment: You need to replace `subfolder` to your subfolder name.

Comment: Woops! This resulted in an internal server error...

`The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.`

`Please contact the server administrator at webmaster@my-domain.com to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.`

`More information about this error may be available in the server error log.`

`Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.`

Comment: Check that your URL's are having the subfolder name too.